# Merge Update in duplicated rows oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a table with repeated rows but with the empty `group_id` field:

| id | reference1 | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA |  |
| 2 | AAAA |  |
| 3 | AAAA |  |
| 4 | BBBB |  |
| 5 | BBBB |  |
| 6 | CCCC |  |
| 7 | CCCC |  |
| 8 | CCCC |  |
| 9 | CCCC |  |
| 10 | CCCC |  |

I need to add a number to the group_id field as long as it is null and I use:

```
UPDATE journals_cv027_tab f1
   SET f1.group_id = journals_seq.nextval
 WHERE f1.group_id IS NULL
   AND EXISTS (SELECT reference1
                 FROM journals_cv027_tab c
                WHERE c.reference1 = f1.reference1);
COMMIT;
```

This just added me a number for each record as follows:

| id | reference1 | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA | 1 |
| 2 | AAAA | 2 |
| 3 | AAAA | 3 |
| 4 | BBBB | 4 |
| 5 | BBBB | 5 |
| 6 | CCCC | 6 |
| 7 | CCCC | 7 |
| 8 | CCCC | 8 |
| 9 | CCCC | 9 |
| 10 | CCCC | 10 |

But I need to assign a number for each group of repeated records for example:

| id | reference1 | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA | 1 |
| 2 | AAAA | 1 |
| 3 | AAAA | 1 |
| 4 | BBBB | 2 |
| 5 | BBBB | 2 |
| 6 | CCCC | 3 |
| 7 | CCCC | 3 |
| 8 | CCCC | 3 |
| 9 | CCCC | 3 |
| 10 | CCCC | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no need a sequence based on your case, you rather can use `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function within a `MERGE` statment with `MATCHED` option, presumingly `id` is a primary key, which can easily be used within the matching condition of the subquery such as

```
MERGE INTO journals_cv027_tab j1 
     USING 
     (SELECT j.*, 
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY reference1) AS dr
        FROM journals_cv027_tab j) j2
          ON ( j2.id = j1.id )
      WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET j1.group_id = dr
     WHERE j1.group_id IS NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/eJ_Bi-fE)</kbd>

If you want to keep the value of the sequential number, then an option would be storing the max value for the group_id within a table which has one row and one column before truncating the table in order to use within the next update as `<that value> + DENSE_RANK()...`

Comment: Hi Barbaros, I really need the sequence because every time I run the process I truncate the data in the table and I need a unique and consecutive number so that it doesn't always start at 1

Comment: Hi @CesarTepetla well, this will do exactly what you need. It will generate unique and consecutive integers , provided that, as I already mentioned, the `id` values are unique and not null. The whole set already will be refreshed to start from 1 after truncation.

Comment: Sure, but I don't want it to always start from 1. I need it to always start from the last number assigned, could you help me place the sequence number please?

Comment: I tried `<that value>` + `DENSE_RANK...` and it worked fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: Separate table should be accessed with `select ... for update` to work correctly in  case of concurrent update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary table to store the values of the groups:

```
create table group_journals_cv027_tab
as 
select reference1, 1 as group_id
from journals_cv027_tab 
group by reference1;

update group_journals_cv027_tab 
set group_id = JOURNALS_SEQ.nextval;

merge into journals_cv027_tab f1
using (select group_id, reference1 from group_journals_cv027_tab) s1
on (f1.reference1 = s1.reference1)
when matched then update set f1.group_id = s1.group_id
where f1.group_id is null;
```